# Eloquent HasManyThrough - User has comments - Comments has answers - So User has answers

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, has-many-through, eloquent-relationship

I have a litle problem implementing a HasManyThrough Relationship in my laravel project.
It's basically a forum app :

We have ---USERS--- who can post ---REPLIES--- in various ---TOPICS---.

```
// USER MODEL
    public function messages(): HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
    }

// TOPIC Model
    public function replies(): HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Reply::class);
    }

// REPLY Model
    public function topic(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Topic::class);
    }
    
    public function user(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

A relation between Replies and Replies exists too : a user can reply to a previous message which was posted by another user

```
// REPLY Model
    public function parent_reply(): BelongsTo {
        return $this->belongsTo(Reply::class, 'parent_reply_id', 'id');
    }

    public function children_replies(): HasMany {
        return $this->hasMany(Reply::class, 'parent_reply_id', 'id');
    }
```

Now, my problem is to create the HasManyThrough relationship which can allow me getting all the message which are answering a specific user's own message.

For example, John post 2 messages : message1 and message 2.

5 users answered to message1, and 3 users answered on message2.

=> I need the relation which give me those 8 answered messages to John. I try this :

```
// User Model
    public function replies() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Reply::class,
            Reply::class,
            'user_id',
            'parent_reply_id',
            'id',
            'id'
        );
    }
```

But I have this error when I test it :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique
> table/alias: 'replies'
>
> select `replies`.*, `replies`.`user_id` as `laravel_through_key` from
> `replies` inner join `replies` on `replies`.`id` =
> `replies`.`parent_reply_id` where `replies`.`user_id` = 3

I dont' understand the *Not unique table/alias: 'replies'* and how to solve it.

If someone could help me, it would be very great :)

Thanks to the community !

Comment: idk how but seems u r trying to join table `replies` with table `replies`, which yeah, seems not good

Comment: It s exactly what I want to do in fact :) but it looks problematic...